# Python Postgres fetchone() - 'int' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, postgresql

I understand this question has been asked many times but in my case I can't find a way to simply resolve it. I have a very basic fetchone() query as below:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=postgres_host,
    database=postgres_database,
    user=postgres_user,
    password=postgres_password)
    
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE status = %s" , (0))
result = cur.fetchone()
print(result[0])
exit
```

I am still getting the result which is the ID of my row cursor returning but right after print statement I get "***'int' object does not support indexing***"

I've been through Stackoverflow for an hour and tried all suggestions but can't find the right answer. Not sure using list is the best approach, as I see it returning a tuple is a very basic query. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64952928/5320906) to the linked duplicate.

Comment: `result` should be the entire table row as selected by `*`. Assuming `id` is the first field in the row then `result[0]` should be `id` and won't result in the indexing error. So either the query is not as you have it in the question or `result[0]` is referring to something other then the output of `cur.fetchone()`.  To your question add `print(result)`.